# getting null in end of arr when looping with for in

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

```
Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback) {
  const newArray = [];
  // Only change code below this line
  for(let i in this){
    newArray.push(callback(this[i], i, this))
  }
  // Only change code above this line
  return newArray;
};

console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].myMap(item => item * 2))
type here
```

The result shows like

`[ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, NaN ]`

I was expecting the result to be like this:

`[ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ]`

can anyone explain me why I have this null at the end of my arr if I use for in loop

**I know this works with normal for loop but I just wanna know why we get this problem
**

Comment: Don't iterate arrays with `for ... in`, or even better, never use `for ... in` at all. Additionally, don't pollute natives, especially with enumerable properties, which is your downfall here. `for ... in` also iterates the prototype chain, and your prototype method is enumerable, so it will be included in the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The `for...in` loop is finding the `myMap` property too. Either do a `Object.hasOwn` check, define the property with `{enumerable: false}`, or don't use `for...in` to loop.

Looping over the elements along with their indexes with [`Array#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries):

```js
Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback) {
  const newArray = [];
  for(const [i, elem] of this.entries()){
    newArray.push(callback(elem, i, this))
  }
  return newArray;
};

console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].myMap(item => item * 2))
```

Checking for own properties:

```js
Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback) {
  const newArray = [];
  for(let i in this)
    if (Object.hasOwn(this, i))
      newArray.push(callback(this[i], i, this));
  return newArray;
};

console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].myMap(item => item * 2))
```

Defining `myMap` with `{enumerable: false}`:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'myMap', {
  value(callback) {
    const newArray = [];
    for (let i in this) {
      newArray.push(callback(this[i], i, this))
    }
    return newArray;
  },
  enumerable: false // this is the default, so it can be omitted
});
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].myMap(item => item * 2))
```

Comment: Ideally, combine the first and last approach.